# Remove one of the legends in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
data = cbind(c("A","B","C","A"), c("John", "Kendra", "Martin", "Steve"), c("12","12","13","14"))
colnames(data) = c("Group", "Name", "Score")
data = as.data.frame(data)
p = ggplot(data, aes(x=Name, y=Score, fill=Name)) + geom_point(pch = 19, aes(col=Group)) + scale_colour_manual(values=c("black", "red", "green"))
print(p)
```

Hey, this code produces two legends: Name and Group. How do I get rid of the legend for Name? I mean the entire legend, not just its title.
Edit: I have just figured it out myself. You do it by saying:

```
p = p + guides(fill=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 5):

I'll slightly adjust your example to something that works for me

You can use `theme` to modify the entire legend, but if you want to restrict your modification to individual elements, use `guide` instead:

```
data <- cbind(c("A","B","C","A"), c("John", "Kendra", "Martin", "Steve"), c("12","12","13","14"))
colnames(data) <- c("Group", "Name", "Score")
data <- as.data.frame(data)

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Name, y = Score, fill = Name)) + 
  geom_point(pch = 19, aes(col = Group)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "red", "green")) +
  guides(fill = FALSE); p
```

Nicely explained in more detail here: [cookbook for R](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: What's the 'f3' bit by the way?

Comment: Sorry, the f3 was just geom_point. Thanks, but you misunderstood my question. I want to remove the whole part of legend for the entries from column Name, not just its title.

Comment: Oups, my bad, apologies! In this case you can use `guides` as well, but just set the entire element to `FALSE`. So instead of `guides(fill = guide_legend(title = NULL))` use `guides(fill = FALSE)`

I've changed my answer accordingly.